# What is the CPU Word size?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5

I have searched everywhere on the internet and i cannot find out how to find the **word size** of a CPU. Can someone either show me where to look or tell me how to find out.

These are the CPU's in particular I need to find the word size for:

*3rd Generation Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3330 quad-core processor [3.0GHz, 6MB Shared Cache]
3rd Generation Intel Core i7-3770 Processor (3.40GHz, 8MB, 4C)

AMD Quad-Core A10-4600M Accelerated Processor (3.2GHz/2.3GHz, 4MB L2 Cache)*

Comment: 64 bit. Almost all curent CPUs are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Intel processors since P4s with the "Prescott" core, including the Pentium D, Core 2 and Core i3/i5/i7 processors have been 64-bit. All recent AMD processors should be the same.

Have you looked at the [Wikipedia article on word size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) yet?

Comment: I am assuming that the 64 bit is the word size? Sorry I am new to this stuff

Comment: Yes, although remember that 64-bit CPUs can also run apps in 32 and sometimes 16-bit mode too. For a detailed discussion check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301007.